# Probability that the random walk goes above $x=a$ and below $x=-b$

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

> Let $X_n$ be a Simple Symmetric Random Walk in 1 dimension, i.e. $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$ where $e_i=\pm1$ each w.p. $1/2$. Let $M_{2n}=\max_{0\leq r\leq 2n}X_r$ and let $m_{2n}=\min_{0\leq r\leq2n}X_r$.
>
> Then find $P(X_0=0,M_{2n}\geq a,m_{2n}\leq -b,X_{2n}=0)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb N$.

I have no idea in proceeding with this problem. I think one has to use reflection principle but how can one use it I do not know. Any help?

Comment: So, you are asking what the probability is that a random walk starts and ends at 0, but touches $a$ and $-b$ on the way? What are the constraints on $n$? Because the probability of this is 1 for arbitrarily large $n$.

Comment: You were told to use reflection principle but you do not, what is the reason? A part of the event of interest is "the walk first hits $a$ then hits $-b$ then is at $0$". Reflecting the part post-hitting time of $a$ around $a$ sends $-b$ to $2a+b$ and $0$ to $2a$. Reflecting the new path post-hitting time of $2a+b$ around $2a+b$ sends $2a$ to $2a+2b$ hence this part of your event has probability $P(X_{2n}=2a+2b,T_{-b}>T_a)$. Can you continue?

Comment: @NikhilMahajan Here the time $2n$ is fixed hence the recurrence of the random walk seems offtopic.